# Azure SQL server migration assistance - Oracle to Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, azure, azure-sql-server

I am asked to migrate the existing on premises Oracle to Azure SQL server using  Azure SQL server migration assistance.

I have no prior experience with Azure SQL server migration assistance and I could not find much information on the internet.

Is there any articles out there to explain the end to end migration process using Azure SQL server migration assistance, especially from Oracle to Azure SQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [**Guide**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/migration-guides/database/oracle-to-sql-database-guide) you can refer to Migrate from Oracle to Azure database  and post migration [Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/post-migration-validation-and-optimization-guide?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: FYI this question is primarily a documentation-request question (which is off-topic). Further, link-only answers are highly discouraged. At best, if you're going to post a link to a document, it should be done only as a comment, not as an answer.