# Azure data factory: data migration from Oracle 12g to Azure SQL server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

I am asked to migrate the existing on premises Oracle to Azure SQL server using Azure data factory.

I have no prior experience with Azure data factory especially on data migration .

Is there any articles out there to explain the end to end migration process using ,Azure data factory especially from Oracle to Azure SQL server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure SQL server migration assistance - Oracle to Azure SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322312/azure-sql-server-migration-assistance-oracle-to-azure-sql)

Comment: No, as SSMA has many limitations, we are asked to use Azure Data factory for data migration.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar There isn't an exist tutorial,  you need combine these two tutorials https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database. Set Oracle as source and Azure SQL Server as Sink.

Comment: @Leon Yue, Thank you. 1st article talks on coping data from Oracle & 2nd Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database. Does it mean that data factory will hold the Oracle data(~1TB) until 2nd step(Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database) being executed?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar yes,  the pipeline will finished until the data transfer completed. The  copy data transfer duration time depends on how large data your have and the data factory resource  you use. May I post these as answer?

Comment: Yes, please, Leon Yue.

Comment: You need to do the copy activity from oracle data source to sql database sink , this will require manually mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an exist tutorial teach us copy from Oracle to Azure SQL database dircetly, you need combine these two tutorials:

1. [Copy data from and to Oracle by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle)
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)

You can build the pipeline, create the Oracle DB as source and Azure SQL Server as sink.

In addition, the pipeline will finished until the data transfer completed. The copy data transfer duration time depends on how large data your have and the data factory resource you use. If you want to improve the data transfer performance, you could ref this document: [Copy activity performance and scalability guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance).

By the way, there are still many limits for the data transfer, data factory would auto convert the data type for us if using auto create table.